# Gnome 3.32 Ctrl+A Select All text missing

Tags: linux, gnome3

I have a question that I can't seem to find related information about. Coming from KDE, I always used to "Select All" text in documents, browsers, input boxes (basically everywhere) but this does not work in Gnome. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> brings my pointer at the beginning of the line and that's it! I am pissed of by this and there is no way to configure it? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which apps are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question here [Ctrl+A does not select all in URL bar in Chrome and Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324862/ctrla-does-not-select-all-in-url-bar-in-chrome-and-firefox)

This was configured at OS level (Ubuntu 19.04) [Emacs Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jaay.png)

Comment: If you click on the checkmark underneath the grey arrowheads to left of the answer, you show the answer was successful, which means a lot in helping other folks with the same issue. You also elevate your karma points.